# Java Client wont negotiate in TLSv1.2 only TLSv1

Tags: java, ssl, nginx, tls1.2

For security reasons I have disabled TLSv1.0 on the NGINX proxy that serves my Java based web app running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.79

A downside to this is that the supplied Pipeline Engine which uses a Java-based framework which is separate but tightly integrated into the web app no longer seems to work. The rest of the web app appears to work fine. If I allow TLSv1.0 connections then the pipeline starts working again.

I have added the following option to the $JAVA_OPTS line in the pipeline launcher config file (-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2) but it makes no difference.

In order to attempt to debug the problem I also added the following to the config file see below results
    -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake

My understanding is that the negotiation begins with the  'Client Hello' message detailing the highest available protocol it can use in this cse TLSv1, this I believe is where it fails as it is not an available protocol server side.

I know there have been similar questions to this on here that involve editing the actual Java code to include but as far as I am aware I do not have access to source code for the pipeline engine.

My question is there any other way to force the Client to use TLSv1.2 when negotiating SSL.

```
        # java -version
        java version "1.7.0_79"
        Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)



*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1497816015 bytes = { 18, 213, 234, 56, 217, 74, 103, 241, 18, 202, 24, 151, 159, 46, 8, 23, 103, 38, 156, 121, 248, 20, 185, 197, 170, 29, 59, 15 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
main, called closeSocket()
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1497816015 bytes = { 208, 101, 162, 96, 138, 72, 236, 117, 195, 28, 5, 230, 64, 245, 31, 236, 168, 113, 208, 15, 23, 86, 193, 115, 252, 1, 42, 254 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:533)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.nrg.xnattools.SessionManager.deleteJSESSION(SessionManager.java:157)
    at org.nrg.pipeline.client.XNATPipelineLauncher.run(XNATPipelineLauncher.java:306)
    at org.nrg.pipeline.client.XNATPipelineLauncher.main(XNATPipelineLauncher.java:260)
```

Comment: Is the web app running in Apache talking via HTTPS to another app? Is not clear to me what that Pipeline Engine is. Can you please clarify the apps and connections involved?

Comment: maybe the pipeline engine is explicitly requesting TLSv1, e.g. with `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1")`. In this case you'll have to accept TLSv1 connections i guess

Comment: `https.protocols` only works if the code is using `(Https)URLConnection` which it apparently is not (no SNI in trace). If the code is directly using `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` you must either change the code or **use java 8** (which also has the benefit of receiving security patches).